# Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/websocket-stream/node_modules/ws/lib/.DS_Store

Tags: npm, homebrew

I was installing imagemagick via brew
`brew install imagemagick`
and then I stumble upon this error message:

```sh
Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/websocket-stream/node_modules/ws/lib/.DS_Store
```

Once `sudo` is not advisable using homebrew, is there any hints on how to solve this issue?

More lines from terminal to give context:

```sh
==> Installing imagemagick
==> Pouring imagemagick-7.0.10-28.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-28: 1,499 files, 25.6MB
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc--9.3.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (84.8MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.18.1... (20 files, 586.8KB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gdbm--1.18.1.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz... (196.2KB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gmp--6.2.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (1022.7KB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c--64.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz... (26.1MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/isl--0.22.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (1.5MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libmpc--1.1.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (114.4KB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mpfr--4.0.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (1.1MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d... (7,983 files, 17.9MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl@1.1--1.1.1d.mojave.bottle.tar.gz... (5.2MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1... (4,036 files, 62.2MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.1... (4,094 files, 62.5MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/readline--8.0.4.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (517.7KB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.31.1... (11 files, 4MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/sqlite--3.31.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz... (1.9MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.4... (92 files, 1MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz... (9.0MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/miniconda--4.7.12.sh... (48.2MB)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gmp... (64B)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mpfr... (64B)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gcc... (64B)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/isl... (64B)
Removing: /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libmpc... (64B)
Pruned 2 symbolic links and 4 directories from /usr/local
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/websocket-stream/node_modules/ws/lib/.DS_Store
```

Comment: That is a question for `brew` and the question is why is imagemagik messing with the `websocket-stream` node.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```